# URL doesnot change after login in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

The URL of login page is localhost:8000/login.
and after login it remain same but i want to return the URL name as the name of form after login as view page like localhost:8000/company_details. can anyone help me for how will i redirect to company_details with compact('company','email') and what will be my route to redirect with these two variables.
Here is my code.

```
if (!empty($login)) {
    return view('company_details',compact('company','email'));
}
```

Comment: So your login form contains some name, and you want to redirect the user there after login?

Or are you already serving the correct file, but the URL stays as /login, but you want it to be /something-else-from-form?

Comment: yes i am returning company_details file but the url is same as login page after login also, and i want it to be same as file name which i am returning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading your edits, I have a better understanding of your problem.

What you are looking for are redirects: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects

Right now, you are saying that when people visit /login, you do some login stuff and return a specific view. Nowhere in your code does it say change the URL.

What you do instead of returning a view, is you redirect the user (see link) to the url you want, or the named route you want. This way the users browsers gets a request to go to another page (/company_details in this case) and changes the url and get whatever you are serving at /company_details.

Comment: after return Redirect('company_details') can i use compact('company','email')

Comment: It's been a while since I used Laravel and it changed over time, but basically when you create a route, you can do whatever you want before returning the actual view.

If you need to send data to the view, you can do either:
- Sessions
- GET parameters
- Parameterized route